# How to get Windows 10 to stop bugging me about updates?

Tags: windows-10, notifications

Every week or so I get a little notification that I have some updates that need to be installed.  9 times out of 10 its the Windows Defender anti-virus definition updates.

How do I get Windows to just install the definition updates and stop posting notifications?

Comment: Have you set the Active Hours, Restart Options, and other automated update settings?

Comment: You can only defer cumulative updates for 14 days and feature updates for 4 months, once the deferment period ends, updates are required if you are running Windows 10 Home or Windows 10 Professional. Deferment options are more limited on Windows 10 Home.  You should set your machine to install updates automatically then you won't be prompted/notified about WD updates.

Comment: @Ramhound Where is the option to install updates automatically?  I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: This isn’t a sarcastic response but the option hasn’t moved.

Comment: @Ramhound Here is my Windows Update window: https://i.imgur.com/9sP7D8u.png

I don't see anything.

Comment: Your already set to install updates unless you are on a metered connection

Comment: I know.  However, every now and then a little popup comes up near the system tray saying that I need to install updates.  And it doesn't go away until, until I dismiss it.

Comment: You can set notifications off in Settings > System > Notifications & actions

Comment: have you tried the scheduled task?

Answer (score 1):

Copy this text into .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2013-12-27T16:14:52.9378367</Date>
    <Author>superuser\MagicAndre1981</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <LogonTrigger>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT1H</Interval>
        <Duration>P1D</Duration>
        <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
      </Repetition>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <Delay>PT1M</Delay>
    </LogonTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>true</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>"C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe"</Command>
      <Arguments>-SignatureUpdate -MMPC</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

and [import it in task scheduler](https://superuser.com/a/485565/174557) and run as `SYSTEM`. Here the update runs in background silently. Edit the trigger/settings like you want.